# Save previous search on .change() JavaScript

Tags: jquery, search, mobile

I'm trying to filter for words using the jquery mobile filter feature and at the same time highlight the word the user is searching for with some code I found here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
      }).replaceWith(function() {
        return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
            return "<span class=\""+" test " + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
        });
      });
    });
  };
  $("#search-basic").change(function(){
    var search = $("input[name=search]").val();
    $(".test").replaceWith(search);
    // This commented part is the part where it creates a los of spans, tried to solve it with the code above but so far it does not work.
    // var unset = $(".test");
    // unset.removeClass("highlight");
    // var search = $("input[name=search]").val();
    $(".testHighlight *").highlight(search, "highlight");
  });


});
```

My problem is that at the end of multiple searches, the user wont be able to see his search words highlighted because the JS created so many < spans > that the function highlight won't find the words.

Is there a way to save the value previously inserted in the search field and then replace the whole < span > with that word? I'm using the .change() function to trigger the whole thing but that way I cannot find the previous value of the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just remove the added `<span>` tags?

```
$("#search-basic").change(function(){
    var elementWithTextToHighlight = $("..."),
        domNode = elementWithTextToHighlight.get(0);

    $("span.highlight").contents().unwrap();  // get rid of the span tags
    domNode.normalize();  // combine all text nodes into one

    var search = $("input[name=search]").val();
    elementWithTextToHighlight.highlight(search, "highlight");
});
```

You should also add a check for an empty string in the highlight script. Otherwise it will add an empty span tag for each character in the text. This would also break the functionality.

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(str, className) {
    if (str === "") {
        return this;
    }
    // the rest of the function...
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32v5jqyu/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.highlight = function(str, className) {
    if (str === "") {
        return this;
    }
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
      }).replaceWith(function() {
        return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
          return "<span class=\"" + " test " + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
        });
      });
    });
  };

  $("#search-basic").change(function () {
    var elementWithTextToHighlight  = $("p"),
        domNode  = elementWithTextToHighlight.get(0);
    $("span.highlight").contents().unwrap().get(0);
    domNode .normalize();
    
    var search = $(this).val();
    elementWithTextToHighlight.highlight(search, "highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<input id="search-basic" type="text" name="search" />
```

Comment: When you try for a second search, it won't highlight the search.

Comment: @LuigiAlver I've edited my answer to address this problem. I had tested my solution only with different words (Lorem, ipsum, ...) not with extensions of the last one (Lorem ipsum, ...) :(